# Difference between SageMaker instance count and Data parallelism

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I can't understand the difference between SageMaker instance count and Data parallelism. As we already have a feature that can specify how many instances we train model when we write a training script using sagemaker-sdk.

However, in 2021 re:Invent, SageMaker team launched and demonstrated SageMaker managed Data Parallelism and this feature also provides distributed training.

I've searched a lot of sites for letting me know about that, but I can't find really clear demonstration. I share some stuffs explaining the concept I mentioned closely. Link : https://godatadriven.com/blog/distributed-training-a-diy-aws-sagemaker-model/

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the instance count will enable SageMaker to launch those many instances and copy data to the instances. This will only enable parallelization at the infrastructure level. To really carry out distributed training we need support at framework/code level where the code should know how to aggregate/send gradients across all the GPU's/instances within the cluster. In some case how to distribute data as well usually when using DataLoaders. To achieve this SageMaker has Distributed Data Parallelism feature built into it. This is similar to other alternatives like Horovod, Pytorch DDP etc...